# Model binding for number with trailing whitespace

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a web api controller with HttpGet method inside.

The controller sets it's route in a parametrized RouteAttribute (**catalogId** doesn't have :int or :long rules by an intention).

The controller's method accepts RequestModel model with the same named property inside.

```
[Route("api/{catalogId}")]
class MyController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult MyMethod([FromRoute]RequestModel model) 
   {
       return Ok(model?.CatalogId ?? "Model.Property is not binded!");
   }
}

public class RequestModel 
{
   [FromRoute]
   public long? CatalogId { get; set; }
}
```

I tested this method by passing valid numbers (e.g. 123, 456), and it worked well:

http://localhost:5000/api/**123**

I also tried to pass numbers with leading or trailing whitespaces and it worked too (e.g. "123%20", "%20456"):

http://localhost:5000/api/**123%20**

As I investigated later, long.Parse method, that is probably used in the defaul model binder, accepts such input according to the default [NumberStyle options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0).

But on some other machines this binding is not done: the property CatalogId is null.
It seems for me, there might be a reason for different parsing rules. I tried to set Thread.CurrentCultue to Invariant one, I tried to apply RequestLocalizationOptions, but it didn't help.

What else can possibly influence on the default Model Binding behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does machines installed exactly same version of dotnet(including patch number)?

Comment: yes, all the same